# What's the default character encoding for Windows in India?

Tags: c#, character-encoding

I know the default encoding for Windows in Western Europe is ISO-8859-1 and the default for web standards is UTF8 but I'm hoping (google is failing me) that someone knows the default for Windows/Visual Studio/C# software in India?

The reason is that we have an India-based company contacting our web services and getting a parse exception and my suspicion is that they aren't setting the encoding right (to UTF8) but testing with the English Windows default (ISO-8859-1) works so I'm investigating alternatives.

Comment: Good question. For the parse exception, can't you log the call parameters from your side?

Comment: Unfortunately we aren't for this particular service and don't have an easy continuous deployment to the customer facing environment so it's non-trivial to insert the logging (though we will do it now to save ourselves the hassle in the future). We log other parse exceptions (It's xml so schema compliance) just in a demonstration of sod's law, not the one they're getting!

Comment: There are 10 [ISCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Script_Code_for_Information_Interchange) code pages listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756.aspx), from Devanagari to Punjabi. Your customer may be using one of them.

Comment: That would have been great, but if you can't.. I will follow the answer to this question anymay, just for my knowledge

Comment: The default character encoding for Windows in Western Europe isn't exactly ISO-8859-1, it's Windows-1252, which has some differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong, but after a bit of research I concluded that if they are not using `en_IN` locale, they have no codepage for either GUI or console.

[This MS official source](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/default.mspx) lists Hindi codepage as 0.

[This random copy of this list](http://www.mydigitallife.info/ansi-code-page-for-windows-system-locale-with-identifier-constants-and-strings/) says that Hindi is a Unicode-only locale.

[IANA claims](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml) codepage numbers 0, 1 and 2 are reserved.

[Here we have Moodle developer](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Table_of_locales) who discovered that while he can use specialised codepages for text files under most of locales, they had to resort to UTF-8 (aka codepage 65001) text files under Hindi locale – files which in most other versions of Windows are called "Unicode files".

[Here we have another developer](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/archive/index.php?t-175876.html) who discovered that Hindi doesn't have a default codepage.

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x8et5ee.aspx), all locale-sensitive functions default to C locale, which means ASCII for 8-bit strings.

So:

1. you cannot type Hindi without Unicode
2. Hindi locale probably treats all bytes >=128 in 8-bit strings as invalid characters, while in Windows-1252 most of them are valid; I'm guessing the application performs too many conversions bytes-text without taking encoding into account (or those Indians do)
3. and finally, other languages of India also have no ANSI codepage

I'm right now on Linux, but if you can, I suggest running programs via Applocale under various locales. I recommend Hindi, Japanese and Turkish – for the largest chance of revealing bugs.

But my bet is that they read that XML off the wire, convert to string with default encoding and it blows up.