# web scraping using powershell

Tags: powershell, web-scraping, web

I am trying to scrape the pages of website https://www.enghindi.com/ .
URLs are saved in csv file, for example

| URL | Hindi meaning |
| --- | --- |
| Url1 | hindi meaning |
| url2 | hindi meaning |

now, everytime I am running following script . it just shows result of only URL1 and that goes into multiple cells. I want all result of url 1 should be in one cell (in hindi meaning box) and similarly for URL2.

url1 : https://www.enghindi.com/index.php?q=close
url2 : https://www.enghindi.com/index.php?q=compose

```
$URLs = import-csv -path C:\Scripts\PS\urls.csv | select -expandproperty urls

  
foreach ($url in $urls)

{
$web = Invoke-WebRequest $url
$data = $web.AllElements | Where{$_.TagName -eq "BIG"} | Select-Object -Expand InnerText 
$datafinal = $data.where({$_ -like "*which*"},'until')
}

foreach ($item in $datafinal) {
[ pscustomobject]@{ Url = $url; Data = $item  } | Export-Csv -Path C:\Scripts\PS\output.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding unicode -Append 
 
     }
```

Are there other ways I can get english to hindi word meaning using web scraping instead of copying and pasting. I prefer google translate but that I think difficult that is why i am trying with enghindi.com.

thanks alot

Comment: The content type has encoding.  You need to specify the hindi encoding  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.3#-contenttype and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384288/whats-the-default-character-encoding-for-windows-in-india

Comment: @jdweng, there is no encoding problem here. The only problem is the structure of the code.

Comment: @mklement0 : The code works with standard characters and does not work with Hindi characters.  The Context Type has to be specified in the Request.

Comment: @jdweng, `(Invoke-WebRequest 'https://www.enghindi.com/index.php?q=close').Headers['Content-Type']` will tell you that the site uses UTF-8 encoding in its responses, which is by definition capable of representing Hindi characters, given that it can represent _all_ Unicode characters.  Running my code will show you that the response is indeed properly decoded. Nowhere in the question is encoding mentioned as a problem. You don't have to _request_ an encoding, you just need to honor the encoding that the _response_ is declared to use, which is what `Invoke-WebRequest` and `Invoke-RestMethod` do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web scraping, due its inherent unreliability, should only be a last resort.
You can make it work in *Windows PowerShell*, but note that the HTML DOM parsing is no longer available in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md).

You code has two basic problems:

- It operates on `$datafinal` *after* the `foreach` loop, at which point you only see the results of the *last* [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) call.
- You loop over each element of array `$datafinal` and create an output object *for each*, instead of creating an output object *per input URL*.

The following reformulation fixes these problems:

```bash
# Sample input URLs
$URLs = @(
  'https://www.enghindi.com/index.php?q=close', 
  'https://www.enghindi.com/index.php?q=compose'
)

$URLs | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $web = Invoke-WebRequest $_
    $data = $web.AllElements | Where { $_.TagName -eq "BIG" } | Select-Object -Expand InnerText 
    $datafinal = $data.where({ $_ -like "*which*" }, 'until')
    # Create the output object for the URL at hand and implicitly output it.
    # Join the $datafinal elements with newlines to form a single vaulue.
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Url = $_
      Hindi = $datafinal -join "`n"
    }
  } | 
  ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Note that, for demonstration purposes, [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv) is used in lieu of [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv), which allows you to see the results instantly.